# Legal way to trade us futures and options from India?

Tags: united-states, india, securities

I wanted to know what is the legal way to trade us futures and options for someone who is resident of India. Currently AFAIK it is illegal for Indians to trade in speculative instruments like futures and options which require leverage for trading. So is there any legal route that retail Indian traders can use to trade us futures and options securities?

Comment: Futures and options don’t require leverage

Comment: @DaleM futures and options are leveraged securities that require margin to open a position.

Comment: No, if you have cash, you can just buy them

Comment: "Currently AFAIK it is illegal for Indians to trade in speculative instruments like futures and options which require leverage for trading." Can you point us to any references supporting this assertion?

Comment: Some derivative trading is leveraged and some isn't. A review of the basics can be found, e.g., at this link https://cleartax.in/s/financial-derivatives